# How can l install ionic using composer?

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, composer-php

I tried installing the `npm` bridge using

```
$ composer require eloquent/composer-npm-bridge:^3
```

with the hope of being able to install packages for ionic using `npm`.

Unfortunately, my plan seems to be failing l seem to get the following error:

> npm WARN @ionic-native/core@4.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1` but none was installed.

Is there a different different way to install ionic on PHP or a solution for my error?

Answer (score 0):

The "error" you are seeing is actually "just" a warning and quite common. Normally it can be safely ignored. It won't hurt the project.